How to set up webpack devServer config to build another target
My project is using webpack v5.89.0.
The package.json has start and prerelease script targets:
scripts": {
  ...,
  "start": "webpack serve --mode development -c webpack.config.js",
  "prerelease": "rm -rf dist/*; npm run build; zip -r dist.zip dist",
  ...
}

To run a live development version of the project via npm run start, I have the following directive in webpack.config.js:
devServer: {
  devMiddleware: {
    writeToDisk: true,
  },
}

To make testing changes faster, I would like to know if it is possible to have the equivalent of the prerelease target also executed automatically each time I make a change in the project, when I have the development service running via npm run start. Are there rules I can add to webpack.config.js or package.json to enable this?

This approach uses the Node.js API for webpack and webpack-dev-server to create a hook that runs on the afterEmit compiler hook for performing custom logic on the build assets each time a file is changed.
Since clean: true already empties the dist/ directory, and webpack dev server rebuilds on file changes, all you really need to do is zip the new build artifacts during dev, hence the zip script in package.json.
package.json
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node devServer.js",
  "zip": "zip -r dist.zip dist"
}

webpack.config.js
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'

export default {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    clean: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      scriptLoading: 'module'
    })
  ]
}

devServer.js
import { execSync } from 'node:child_process'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import webpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server'
import config from './webpack.config.js'

const compiler = webpack(config)
/**
 * You can put your prerelease logic here.
 * Run an npm script or anything else.
 */
compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', () => {
  console.log('The build has finished!')
  execSync('npm run zip')
})
const server = new webpackDevServer(
  {
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true
    }
  },
  compiler
)
const runServer = async () => {
  await server.start()
}

server.startCallback(() => {
  console.log('The server is running!')
})

runServer()

The source code can be whatever, this is just an example.
src/index.js
const p = document.createElement('p')
const text = document.createTextNode(`import.meta.url is ${import.meta.url}`)

p.appendChild(text)
document.body.appendChild(p)

From here you can npm run start and then navigate to http://localhost:8080. Make a change to src/index.js and notice the archive dist.zip be recreated.

you can use webpack watch with afterEmit hook to run custom task or make use of nodemon to watch and trigger prerelease script on change

Add the following line to your code,
YourWebpackConfig = {
     // other config 

     output: {
              // other config
              clean: true
     }

}

You can also refer the following docs https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#cleaning-up-the-dist-folder
